# Using Spark to merge two or more files content and manipulate the content

Tags: apache-spark, awk, sed, pyspark

Can I use Spark to do the following? 
I have three files to merge and change the contents:

1. First File called column_header.tsv with this content:

   ```
   first_name last_name address zip_code browser_type
   ```
2. Second file called data_file.tsv with this content:

   ```
   John    Doe 111 New Drive, Ca   11111   34
   Mary    Doe 133 Creator Blvd, NY    44499   40
   Mike    Coder   13  Jumping Street  UT  66499   28
   ```
3. Third file called browser_type.tsv with content:

   ```
   34  Chrome
   40  Safari
   28  FireFox
   ```
4. The final_output.tsv file after Spark processing the above should have this contents:

   ```
   first_name last_name address zip_code browser_type
   John    Doe 111 New Drive, Ca   11111   Chrome
   Mary    Doe 133 Creator Blvd, NY    44499   Safari
   Mike    Coder   13  Jumping Street  UT  66499   FireFox
   ```

Is this do able using Spark?  Also I will consider Sed or Awk if it is possible use the tools.  I know the above is possible with Python but I will prefer using Spark to do the data manipulation and changes.  Any suggestions?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: File merging and manipulations are totally doable in spark. You just need to come up with your own logic to manipulate your rows before merging them.

Answer (score 1):

Here it is in awk, just in case. Notice the file order:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{ a[$1]=$2;next }{ $NF=($NF in a?a[$NF]:$NF) }1' file3 file1 file2
```

Output:

```
first_name last_name address zip_code browser_type
John Doe 111 New Drive, Ca 11111 Chrome
Mary Doe 133 Creator Blvd, NY 44499 Safari
Mike Coder 13 Jumping Street UT 66499 FireFox
```

Explained:

```
NR==FNR {                            # process browser_type file
    a[$1]=$2                         # remember remember the second of ...
    next }                           # skip to the next record
{                                    # process the other files
    $NF=( $NF in a ? a[$NF] : $NF) } # replace last field with browser from a
1                                    # implicit print
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. Read header:

```
with open("column_header.tsv") as fr:
    columns = fr.readline().split()
```

Read `data_file.tsv`:

```
users = spark.read.option("delimiter", "\t").csv("data_file.tsv").toDF(*columns)
```

Read `called browser_type.tsv`:

```
browsers = spark.read.csv("called browser_type.tsv") \
    .toDF("browser_type", "browser_name")
```

Join:

```
users.join(browser, "browser_type", "left").write.csv(path)
```